# How to dynamically keep track on button click count on ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I want to make a form where people can sign up for a course. Number of people for a course is limited. I want to make a page where user can see how many places are still available and that number is dynamically updated, so if another user signs for a course the other one sees change. When number of available places reaches 0 the signup button should be disabled. Such task should be easy to implement but I am afraid it is not. I suppose some Ajax will be involved but how to handle server side counting? WebServices? I have a problem to design a logic behind all of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technology/technique you're looking for is called Server Push.

Basic idea: Client should respond to some events happening on Server.

Possible solutions:

1. Polling some server action via AJAX in a timely fashion;
2. Keeping long-running AJAX request open on server-side until timeout occurs or event happens, then process acquired result on client (determine if it was server action or just timeout), reestablish connection from client if necessary.

and a couple of other solutions which are basically variations of the above two. Also solution will much depend on server-side technology you're using.

Google has a short yet very informative article on what this technique is and how it can be implemented [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/ServerPushFAQ). It's (almost) technology agnostic so it should help you to understand concepts and possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a database on the server. For the "courses" table, have an associated table containing the "bookings". Add them up in a SQL query.